# Is it possible to find out how long another app has been running? Android

Tags: java, android

For example, can you find out how long facebook or gmail has been running?

I've tried using PackageManager but I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't say "NO", but chances are you should not be able to know that "unless" the application wants you to know that, in android each application is a "sandbox" and even tho there are components that you can use to get some information about other apps, unless you have a rooted phone you will only know about another app whatever the other app exposes through AIDL or a "ContentResolver". Imagine how insecure would it be if you could know anything you want about other apps...

Hope it helps!

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :)
There is this app called "App Usage Tracker" that does this and I was trying to do the same thing.